# AES-256-CBC encrypt with key / IV in java and decrypt in OpenSSL

Tags: java, encryption, openssl

I'm struggling with openssl and aes encryption. I need to encrypt a file in java while forcing the key and IV values instead of using a password. It must be decipher with the following command:

```bash
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -K $KEY_VALUE -iv $IV -in hello.txt.ssl -out hello-clear.txt
```

Sadly, I can not change this command, it's the requirement of the client.

I managed to encrypt the file in java (see following code) but I get this error when decrypting it with openssl

```
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
bad decrypt
40874B28DD7F0000:error:1C800064:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_unpadblock:bad decrypt:providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon_block.c:124:
```

Any idea of what I missed in the encryption process ? Or any other way to do it ?

*Here is the full java sample that encrypt and generate the decryption command:*

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class OpenSslEncryptor {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        int keyLength = 256;
        int keyLengthInBit = keyLength / 8;

        File baseFile = new File("hello.txt");
        IOUtils.write("hello openssl !", new FileOutputStream(baseFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] inBytes = new FileInputStream(baseFile).readAllBytes();

        String keyValue = generateRandom(40);
        String iv = generateRandom(16);
        byte[] keyValueB = Arrays.copyOfRange(keyValue.getBytes(), 0, keyLengthInBit);
        byte[] ivB = Arrays.copyOfRange(iv.getBytes(), 0, 16);

        final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValueB, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivB));

        byte[] data = cipher.doFinal(inBytes);

        File outputFile = new File(baseFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".ssl");
        IOUtils.write(data, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        String decryptCommand = "openssl aes-256-cbc -d -K " + keyValue
                + " -iv " + iv
                + " -in " + outputFile.getName()
                + " -out hello-clear.txt";

        System.out.println(decryptCommand);
    }

    private static String generateRandom(int length) {
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            builder.append(Integer.toHexString(secureRandom.nextInt(16)));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is the command line encrypt with openssl if anyone want it

```bash
openssl aes-256-cbc -e -K $KEY_VALUE -iv $IV -in hello.txt -out hello.txt.ssl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `generateRandom()` method returns the data hex encoded. When a sequence of *y* bytes is hex encoded, it consists of *2*y* hex digits. Accordingly, key and IV must be generated with twice the required length (64 for the 32 bytes key for AES-256, 32 for the 16 bytes IV for AES). These can then be hex decoded for use in encryption, e.g. with `HexFormat.of().parseHex()`:

```java
String keyValue = generateRandom(64); 
String iv = generateRandom(32); 
byte[] keyValueB = HexFormat.of().parseHex(keyValue);
byte[] ivB = HexFormat.of().parseHex(iv);
```

---

Overall, however, the generation of the random data in `generateRandom()` is somewhat cumbersome and could be refactored, e.g.:

```java
byte[] keyValueB = generateRandom(32);
byte[] ivB = generateRandom(16);
String keyValue = HexFormat.of().formatHex(keyValueB);
String iv = HexFormat.of().formatHex(ivB);
...
private static SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
private static byte[] generateRandom(int lengthInBytes) {
    byte[] data = new byte[lengthInBytes];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(data);
    return data;
}
```

Now `generateRandom()` produces the required data directly as `byte[]`. These can then be hex encoded for the OpenSSL statement, e.g. with `HexFormat.of().formatHex()`.